# Storage Spaces - Reduced Rebuild Time for Reseated Drive

Tags: storage-spaces

Does Windows Storage Spaces implement optimized/reduced rebuilding of a mirror or parity drive group if a drive is mistakenly removed and added again?

I have some limited exposure to storage spaces in an enterprise environment, and toy around with it a bit at home as well. I noticed recently that when accidentally disconnecting a drive that is part of a mirror, then reconnecting it shortly after (15-30min), it seems like the time spent in a "Repairing" state is drastically lower than if a drive is removed and "replaced" triggering a full re-mirror.

I can't seem to spot any write-ups or documentation on functionality like this, but I could imagine that Storage Spaces would perform some kind of tracking on which "slabs" are modified during the time the offending drive is not connected, and only performs a repair on the applicable data.

Any first-hand experience or observations would be helpful, though documentation would be helpful (though I'm fairly sure there is none specific to this after a good amount of searching).

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is that the recommended design for storage spaces is to have redundancy across enclosures.

So in a mirror setup, one enclosure would be the mirror of the other enclosure. I'd hate to do a firmware upgrade on the first enclosure, and then get a full rebuild once it comes back online.. so I'm pretty sure that there is some logic involved - certified enclosures give notice about drives being removed which probably triggers a full rebuild.